# Querying unique records in concurrent queries with Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, locking

I am trying to implement Oracle database locking in Spring Boot app. Here is the use case: the service should query DB to fetch the list of records corresponding to some criteria, e.g.

```
select * from books where book_status='available';
```

This query returns the list of all `available` books and we just return the first book from the list and then update `book_status` to `unavailable`:

```
update books set book_status='unavailable' where book_name='testName';
```

Now, in concurrent queries there is a chance 2 queries can return the same book which should never happen - we should always return different books.

To achieve that I tried to use `select for update` queries:

```
select * from books where book_status='available' for update;
```

But that approach didn't help I several concurrent queries returned the same record.

I also tried to use JPA to lock the records but that also didn't help:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Books where book_status='available'");
query.setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
query.getResultList();
```

Can somebody help to figure out how I can always get different records in concurrent queries?

Comment: Use a transaction?

Comment: @123 Could you refer me to the right source to read about transactions? Will it work on database level?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT016

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

Comment: @123 thanks! Could you also suggest transaction isolation level for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what is going on with `Select for update` returning the same rows. But this is my current mental model what is going on:

The first select/thread selects and locks the rows. 
The second selects the same rows and tries to obtain a lock but can't until the first commits. 
I'd expect it to then see the updated version of the row and not return it. 
But either way you are blocking which doesn't seem to make much sense for your case.

An optimistic lock won't help either, because an optimistic lock isn't a lock in the conventional sense. 
It lets you process the data and only when writing it back to the database checks that nobody else changed it.
Not what you want as far as I can tell.

What you need to do is mark the books as being processed by a given process.
You could do that with the following process:

Update the first N rows as being processed by the current job.
A statement like the following should do:

```
update books b
    set book_status = 'processed by ' || :jobname
    where id in (
        select id
        from books b2 
        where book_status = 'available'
        ORDER BY name
        NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
    )
```

Run this in a separate transaction that gets immediately committed.
Springs [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) is often a better fit for such short lived transactions.

Now the main part of the job may select the marked rows without any other job interfering until `book_status` is set to `unavailable` or back to `available` if you want to make a book available to other jobs again.

If the processing happens in a single  transaction you should be able to get basically the same effect with [`SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/skip_locked)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61914177/66686) deals with the same basic problem although from a slightly different perspective.